# Efficiently insert integers into a growing array if no duplicates

Tags: c++, algorithm

There is a data structure which acts like a growing array. Unknown amount of integers will be inserted into it one by one, if and only if these integers has no dup in this data structure.

Initially I thought a `std::set` suffices, it will automatically grow as new integers come in and make sure no dups.

But, as the set grows large, the insertion speed goes down. So any other idea to do this job besides hash?

Ps

I wonder any tricks such as xor all the elements or build a Sparse Table (just like for rmq) would apply?

Comment: Is there an upper bound on the value of the integers?

Comment: @Jon, the upper bound in 2∧32

Comment: Can you give the complexities of these operations? If we don't have them, many data structures are possible. For example, a binary tree or a linked list.

Comment: @Ben the desired insertion complexity would be o(1) if possible.

Comment: Do you know the order of magnitude of the number of integers?  Is it likely to be 10's, 1000's or 1000000's?

Comment: What do you want to do with the result? Find if a given integer is in? Find the min/max? Find continuous intervals? Depending on your answer better approaches are possible.

Comment: @user1666959 find if a given integer is in

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to spend memory on the problem, 2^32 bits is 512MB, at which point you can just use a bit field, one bit per possible integer.  Setting aside CPU cache effects, this gives O(1) insertion and lookup times.

Without knowing more about your use case, it's difficult to say whether this is a worthwhile use of memory or a vast memory expense for almost no gain.

Comment: I thought of bit map, but afraid of vast mem expense for no gain. Thanks any way

Comment: Actually, I think this is going to be about as fast as you can get.  By insertion, I think Jon means doing something like `seen_numbers[number] = true;`, assuming you are using something like `vector<bool>`.

Answer (score 2):

This site includes all the possible containers and layout their running time for each action ,
so maybe this will be useful :

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

Seems like unordered_set as suggested is your best way.

Answer (score 1):

If there is some range the numbers fall in, then you can create several `std::set` as buckets.

EDIT- According to the range that you have specified, `std::set`, *should* be fast enough. O(log n) is fast enough for most purposes, unless you have done some measurements and found it slow for your case.

Also you can use [Pigeonhole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) along with `sets` to reject any possible duplicate, (applicable when set grows large).

Comment: No range, they are just 32 bits integer

Comment: @Alcott: Then, there is indeed a range :) `0 - 4294967295`

Comment: @Alcott: It depends upon the kind of input you are expecting. Here is an example - assume there are multiple sets, and one bucket ranges from 10000 to 25000, if a element fall in this range, you just need to check the size of this particular set, if it is = 15000, you don't need to execute `insert()`, since this element is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a `std::unordered_set`, which should be implemented as a hash table (well, I do not understand why you write "besides hash"; `std::set` normally is implemented as a balanced tree, which should be the reason for insufficient insertion performance).

Comment: Yes, set is implemented using rb tree? As the tree grows higher, insertion speed goes down. Hash is ok, but I just want some new idea.

Comment: Red-Black trees give reasonably good, consistent performance (low variability), but aren't nearly as fast on average as Treaps.  A set datatype based on hash tables is probably best here.

Answer (score 0):

A bit vector can be useful to detect duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Even more requirements would be necessary for an optimal decision. This suggestion is based on the following constraints:
Alcott 32 bit integers, with about 10.000.000 elements (ie any 10m out of 2^32)

It is a BST (binary search tree) where every node stores two values, the beginning and the end of a continuous region. The first element stores the number where a region starts, the second the last. This arrangement allows big regions in the hope that you reach you 10M limit with a very small tree height, so cheap search. The data structure with 10m elements would take up 8 bytes per node, plus the links (2x4bytes) maximum two children per node. So that make 80M for all the 10M elements. And of course, if there are usually more elements inserted you can keep track of the once which are not.
Now if you need to be very careful with space and after running simulations and/or statistical checks you find that there are lots of small regions  (less than 32 bit in length), you may want to change your node type to one number which starts the region, plus a bitmap.

If you don't have to align access to the bitmap and, say, you only have continuous chunks with only 8 elements, then your memo requirement becuse 4+1 for the node and 4+4 bytes for the children. Hope this helps.